# Vue3 how send props to created child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Props are initialized, but after `.mount` they disappear. How should I properly setup `props` with dynamically loaded components?

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'

blockView = createApp(Block);
blockView.props = {
    type: json['type'],
    title: json['title'],
    subtitle: json['subtitle']
}
blockView.mount(this.$refs.container)
```

Answer (score 1):

Props are not available to the App, just components, however I've found that these work for passing values to an appplication.

### 1. Use inject/provide

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
    inject: ['name'],
    // ...etc
})
app.provide("name", "Ludwig")
app.mount('#app2')
```

This is not exactly a prop (and needs to be passed before mount), but could work for you.

more info:  https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#provide

### 2. Nest as render function and wrap

By wrapping in render function, you can pass the props. If you wrap that again in your custom mount function, you can  customize to allow passing props.

```js
// the app as a component
const appComponent = Vue.defineComponent({
  name: "appComponent",
  props: {
    name: {}
  },
  // ...etc
})

// wrap mount function
const mountApp = (selector, props) => {
  // the actual app is just a simple render function
  const app = Vue.createApp({
    components: { appComponent },
    render() {
      return Vue.h(appComponent, props)
    }
  })
  // mount to the passed selector
  app.mount(selector);
}

// call function with props
mountApp('#app1', {
  name: "Darla"
});
```

example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dapo/e9326fq4/)

Comment: there are another method to create child component in vue3 with props? Instead of .createApp

Comment: `createApp` creates a vue app. Components are created using `defineComponent` or `component` if you have the app instance